# Windows 2003 random freeze without anything in logs

Tags: windows-server-2003

We have a Windows 2003 IBM rack server bought in 2008.
2 x 2 core Xeon, 4 Gb RAM, hardware RAID 1 for system and RAID 5 for datas.
Old software, not so old hardware. Everything went well until recently.
This computer served very few things. Some files for 2 users, a Tomcat server for about 1000 hits per day, and a script running 24/7 to feed the Tomcat from another computer.

About 4 weeks ago, we decided to use this (oversized for the current use) server to share more files. About 350 Gb of Word/Excel/whatever for about 150 users.

Since then, the server freeze about twice a week.
Logs are empty of any suspicious events.
The server now reboot each night, but nothing better.
I ran Memtest during hours: no error
The RAID software show nothing into its log.

When the problem occur:
1. some users complain about the fact they can't access their files
2. I log on the server (30 seconds or 30 minutes later)
3. I can do whatever for about 30 seconds
4. the mouse can move, and nothing else work
5. the hard drives lights blink about once every 2 seconds

I then force a poweroff with the main switch, and reboot.

Any idea on where/how I can dig for more informations ? Since the Windows logs show nothing special, I don't have a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File system auditing, network , disk io CPU and memory performance monitoring.
Since this happened when you started sharing out more files one of these metrics will likely find you the culprit.